# Error preg_match invalid phone number

Tags: php, regex

```
$phone = 841657196818;
$phone = 841267337430;

if(preg_match("/^[1-9]{2}[0-9]{8|9|10}$/", $phone)) {
   echo "$phone Valid"; 
} else {
   echo "$phone Invalid.";
}
```

Why is `841657196818` valid, but `841267337430` is not valid?

Comment: I've never seen `{8|9|10}` is that suppose to allow 8-10 numbers ranging between 0 and 9?

Comment: exactly... i think the regex is checking for `8`, `9` or `10` at the end

Comment: It's either suppose to be checking for 8, 9, or 10; or 8 to 10 individual numbers. Not sure which, I'd think the 8-10 numbers.

Comment: hope you don't expect my phone number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK `{8|9|10}` is not syntactically correct. You want `{8,10}` which basically means 'from 8 to 10'.

The corrected syntax is `^[1-9]{2}[0-9]{8,10}$`.

[Example](http://3v4l.org/Ypmo7)